# How can I save file’s to the user’s computer via JavaScript in Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I need to create a persistent file and save about 50mb of data in it.

[The FileSystem API only works in Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem). Is there another way to create local files that works in latest versions of Firefox and IE?

Comment: In short, no. The file access APIs seem to be being abandoned: see http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/